# How to properly create an alias to a content

Tags: nodes, path-aliases

When I create a content from Dashboard, I assign it an alias, to be exact I assign it:

> `offers`

But the route I'm getting is:

> `http://example.com/?q=offers`

How can I make it to be just:

> `http://example.com/offers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Drupal Stack Exchange :-)

You need to Enable Clean URL's .. Find more information regarding Clean URL's in D.O [here](https://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls)

Go to  "admin/config/search/clean-urls" and enable clean URL's

[image]